# What is the correlation coefficient between two zero random variables?

Tags: probability, correlation

What is $\rho_{XY}$ when $X=0$ and $Y=0$? For all $X=Y$, $\rho_{XY}=1$ and this should be no exception. But using the following: $$\rho_{XY}=\frac{E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}$$ yields a $\frac{0}{0}$ form. How do I take the limits or apply L'Hospital's rule to prove this equals 1?

Comment: When one standard deviation is zero, the correlation is not defined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correlation is undefined.  It *should* be an exception because the variance is zero.

To see why limits won't work, let $X$ be *any* random variable with a nonzero variance and (without any loss of generality) suppose it has a mean of zero.  Then the sequences of *bivariate* random variables $(X/n, X/n)$ and $(X/n, -X/n)$ both converge in probability to $(0,0)$ as $n\to\infty$, but the correlations in the first sequence are all $1$ and those in the second sequence are all $-1$. Thus you cannot sneak up on a correlation for $(0,0)$ by taking limits--the limit of the correlations can be $1$, $-1$ (or indeed any value in between).

Comment: The geometry should make this easy to see. Two variables identically zero collapse the data to a single point in the plane, which is consistent with any (every!) straight line through that point. If the slope of the line is indeterminate, the correlation is undefined.

Comment: @Nick It sounds like you might object to Peter Flom's answer, then, because when $Y$ has zero variance but $X$ does not, there geometrically *is* a line and it has zero slope, whereas he claims (correctly, I believe) that in such a case the correlation is *still* undefined.

Comment: I don't object to his argument. From the perspective I adopted there is also a contradiction. From the geometry $Y$ is perfectly predictable from $X$, but the converse isn't true, and for a correlation to be valid such a contradiction can't arise.

Comment: @Nick So we see that it's not purely a matter of the geometry of one point, is it? :-).  Even prediction might not be the right way to be looking at this: after all, in the case where both variables have zero variance, each indeed *is* "perfectly predictable" from the other.  That sounds like an argument that their correlation coefficient ought to be considered $1$!  (Of course I'm just tweaking you a little bit--this is a truly minor issue and we have no disagreement--but sometimes an examination of such "edge" cases can provide deeper insight into the underlying concepts.)

Comment: Very good point: predictability is not the only game. I was answering the original question, not claiming to provide a knock-down argument for all pathological cases. Arguments can collapse, or be refuted, for different reasons. For (constant, constant') no correlation is definable geometrically; For (constant, y) or (x, constant) no correlation can be defined consistently. I usually try to teach this as saying that you can't define a correlation if there isn't a linear relationship, but then the rest of the argument consists of a Pickwickian interpretation of "relationship".

Answer (score 4):

$\frac{0}{0}$ seems correct to me. That is, it's meaningless. The correlation measures the linear relationship between two variables. But if either variable is a constant this is a meaningless idea. It isn't 0, it isn't 1, it's just ... not. So, $\frac{0}{0}$ seems right.